# "Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app" when deploying heroku-buildpack-nodejs and heroku-buildpack-ruby-minimal

Tags: heroku, deployment, buildpack

I'm using heroku-buildpack-multi:

```
BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

I'm trying to deploy with two buildpacks and am getting the following error:

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 325 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

Here are the contents of my .buildpack

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/dpiddy/heroku-buildpack-ruby-minimal.git
```

It used to be intermittent but it's now happening every time I try to deploy.

Strangely enough, the official heroku ruby project seems to have gone missing...
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby

Note that it is still on this page: https://github.com/heroku

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby is back. Seems like it was a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 8):

You need a package.json for the node buildpack. So, something like:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "my-rad-proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~0.10.21"
  }
}
```

As well as the Gemfile for ruby.

Comment: i was missing "engines": {
    "node": "~0.10.21"
  }

Comment: The package.json has to be in the root dir of the repository.